# Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I recently purged MySQL but now I am unable to reinstall it using:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

I get the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  mariadb-server-10.2

E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate
```

Although there are many such questions on the internet, none of them are working. I am desperate here please help.

I am using UBUNTU 17.10 x64

Comment: [First hit from google](https://websiteforstudents.com/installing-mysql-latest-versions-ubuntu-17-04/).

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 is no longer actively supported (July 19, 2018), you may want to upgrade to ensure you get updates/patches/fixes.

Comment: As this is now 2 ubuntu install questions today. Maybe you should familiarise yourself with how software installation works on Ubuntu by reading the manual. If not that then a google search tutorial may be of use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is urgent, try restoring from your backup.

Comment: Though this is not a permanent solution, it worked fine. Thanks